# How to use dialogflow module of in nodejs to create messenger bot (using dialogflow v2 API)

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I am created one facebook messenger bot. This working fine but I am created this using apiai module now I want to create a bot using dialogflow module means using dialogflow V2 API.

Can you please share sample code or reference using which I can able to create facebook messenger bot of which will integrate the facebook app and dialogflow (using node js dialogflow module). Not by using dialogflow fullfillment inline editor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://www.yudiz.com/chatbot-for-facebook-messenger-using-dialogflow-and-node-js-part1/) tutorial for reference. It contains webhook fulfillment!

Comment: Thanks, sai.raj. But This tutorial for v1 and I am searching tutorial for v2 api which is latest library of dialogflow (dialogflow module of nodejs)